# Create a PDF in PHP without using fopen

Tags: php, pdf

I need to create a PDF on a PHP page for a client whose web host has disabled fopen. All of the PHP->PDF frameworks I've seen so far use fopen to add images to the PDF. Is there either a framework that doesn't use fopen, or another way to create PDFs in PHP.

I've used the FPDF framework up to now, and looked at dompdf and mpdf. (I've got a few others to look at but thought I'd ask here if someone has got experience).

I tried using curl with FPDF but ran into streaming errors.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: At the end you would like to save the file to the disk (on the server)?

Comment: Not much you can do if you don't have `fopen`, it's more trouble than it's worth. Tell your client that their host is unreasonable and there are a million other hosts which don't restrict vital functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `fopen` is disabled, it is very likely that all other functions to access the file system (like `file_get_contents()`) are disabled as well. A PHP PDF  library will have to use *some*  function to access the image, so there is probably no way to do this under the current conditions.

Your client will have to talk to the web host about re-enabling those functions, or look for a new provider. That might be a good idea anyway: disabling all filesystem functions is really excessive and silly, and possibly a symptom of bigger underlying security issues - I can see no reason to do this on a properly configured system.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. I agree that it's not an ideal situation to be in and would prefer to have fopen enabled. Anyway, I managed to find TCPDF which somehow works, so I now have to replace the current PDF code with the new one.